# connecting a set of points with lines in R

Tags: r

At present, I generate a figure using the following script

```
 dat <- matrix(runif(1000*99),99,1000)
 dat <- rbind(rep(0.1,1000),dat)
 out <- cmdscale(dist(dat),k = 2)
 plot(out)
 points(out[1,1],out[1,2],col = "red")
```

[image]

Based on the above figure, I want to connect that red point with other points, how to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "connect"? You could do `lines(out)` which connects the points in the order in which they were generated. Or do you mean by y value?

Comment: What do you mean? You want to all the points to be connected by lines, or you just want that one point to be connected to some other point? Which point?

Comment: What he ^ said. I've voted to close until we get clarification...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to connect all the points to that red point, you could try...

```
segments(out[1,1],out[1,2],out[,1],out[,2])
```

[image]

Adjusting the order of the printing and the graphical characteristics could make it a little easier to look at too:

```
dat <- matrix(runif(1000*99),99,1000)
dat <- rbind(rep(0.1,1000),dat)
out <- cmdscale(dist(dat),k = 2)
plot(out,type="n")
segments(out[1,1],out[1,2],out[,1],out[,2],col="#cccccc")
points(out,col="black",pch=20)
points(out[1,1],out[1,2],col = "red",pch=20)
```

[image]